# NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/lwuit/layouts/Layout error?

Tags: eclipse, java-me, lwuit

i am developing an java application using eclipse pulser ide, in that i have got `NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/lwuit/layouts/Layout.

i have tried many solution's and tried to import LWUIT.jar and cleaned project's but even its not working can anybody head up with a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to project Properties, Java Build Path, Order and Export and make sure that your LWUIT jar is marked.